# Simple way to populate a List with a range of Datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I trying to find a simple way to solve this.

I have a Initial Date, and a Final Date.

And I want to generate a `List<Datetime>` with each of the dates in a given period.

---

**Example** : Initial Date is "2013/12/01" and Final Date is "2013/12/05".

And I want to automatically populate a list with

```
"2013/12/01"
"2013/12/02"
"2013/12/03"
"2013/12/04"
"2013/12/05"
```

---

What would you suggest me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just adding one day until you hit the final date?

Comment: @JustinPihony Yes, but I was looking some inline solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 5);

var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(endDate - startDate).TotalDays + 1)
                      .Select(x => startDate.AddDays(x))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: A solution with Enumerable.Range() was just what I want. I've tried before ask this question it, but missed some details. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
for(var day = from.Date; day.Date <= end.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
{
     list.Add(day);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 1); // or any other start date
int numberOfDays = 5;
var dates  = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfDays)
                       .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i))
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq like:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 5);
List<DateTime> dates =
                      Enumerable.Range(0, ((endDate - startDate).Days) + 1)
                      .Select(n => startDate.AddDays(n))
                      .ToList();
```

For output:

```
foreach (var item in dates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToShortDateString());
}
```

Output:

```
01/12/2013
02/12/2013
03/12/2013
04/12/2013
05/12/2013
```

Comment: `-1 for encouraging users to continue with their bad questions on SO`

Comment: @EZI, lol for revenge downvote, like it matters. Look at the number of votes against your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26047285/2711965)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime, @increment int
SET @startdate = '2013/12/01'
SET @enddate = '2013/12/05'
SET @increment = 0
WHILE DATEADD(dd, @increment, @startdate) <= @enddate
  BEGIN
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, @increment, @startdate)
    SET @increment = @increment + 1
  END
```

Inside the while loop you can put the values on a table or do whatever you wish instead of just printing them out.

Comment: Why did you post that? Is there any sign the question is about SQL?

Comment: my mistake Marcin - I thought I had set the filter to "SQL". I realized it wasn't a sql question when I saw the other answers after I had posted mine.