# Split on every fourth comma in a string and count

Tags: c#, split

I have a string like this:
    1,b,1,28,2,g,9,95,3,y,4,60,4,r,4,8,5,b,10,46,6,b,10,45,7,g,8,94,8,r,8,16,9,y,3,58,15,r,10,20,16,g,5,87,19,r,1,2,21,y,1,54,22,b,3,31,1,r,9,17

I want to split this every fourth time I hit a comma and afterwards count how many times it has been split, but I have no idea how to do so :-/

I came across this, but it is JavaScript and I want to be able to do this in [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29):

```
var j:int = 0;
var h:String;
for(var thisvalue:String in thestring){
    h += (j%4 == 3)?thisvalue+';':thisvalue+','; 
    j++;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a free code translation service

Comment: So why not use the String Split method, count the number of elements in the ensuing array, and then divide by 4?

Comment: Do you need to store the values or just count how many times it would be split? If you need to store them, do you also need to keep the commas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var cnt = (thestring.Count(x => x == ',') + 1) / 4;
```

Comment: Not sure where the "x" comes from?

Comment: -1 for encouraging users to continue with their bad questions on SO

Comment: @user2711965, i'm not so sure what people are up in arms about.  OP shows research having found an example in JS.  We're here to help.  I'll counter your -1 ;)

Comment: @Mansa, `x` is an automatically declared variable as part of the lambda expression that is being used here. the `x =>` declares x as one of the characters in the string.

Comment: @Mansa: Here is a quick read on Lambda expressions in C# to clarify the x part: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-minutes

Comment: Yes I don't know why people are jumping all over this question with their downvotes. It is a valid question by (presumably) a beginner to C# and some effort was already put into finding a solution. Just because it is an easy thing to do for someone with some C# experience, doesn't mean it is a bad question.

Comment: @JasonDown No it is not a valid question. OP doesn't show any effort to write it in c#. He/She simply asks people to translete the code he/she found  at internet.

Answer (score 0):

C# has a String.Split function that will split the initial string into an list of strings based on the comma.  You then need a loop that recombines the ones you want as a single string into a single string